# Find, and sort results by date created

Tags: linux, find, sort

How can I sort the results of `find`? I want to sort by date created asc?

```
find /docs -type f | sort
```

Sorts by filename not date created. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AFAIK, Linux doesn't record the creation time, so the short answer is you cannot.

For the modification time, try this:

```
$ find /docs -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -k1 -n
```

or:

```
$ find /docs -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c "%y %n" | sort
```

Comment: You beat me too it!  Justin, for some discussion on what ctime actually means, look at http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=741616

Comment: I'm getting:

stat: illegal option -- c
usage: stat [-FlLnqrsx] [-f format] [-t timefmt] [file ...]

Comment: Which distro are you using?