# Linux - Date of the latest modified file in a folder

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, web-server, website

What I want to accomplish here is this:

I have an apache website, and on that website, I want to display something like

```
Latest website update: 01/12/2011 at 6h32 AM
```

I had an idea on how to do this. I could write an hourly script that checks the date of the latest modified file in the **/var/www**. And then store this value in a file or in the database for fast access.

How can I do this, and if you have a better idea, please share it with me.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/335384/59925

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives the exact output you asked for in your question:

`echo "Latest website update: $(date -d @$(find /var/www -type f -exec stat -c%Z {} \; | sort | tail -1) "+%d/%m/%Y at %lh%M %p")"`

Latest website update: 02/12/2011 at  8h55 PM

It was a fun one-liner to puzzle together, but I wouldn't recommend using it. It will probably be slow.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, and it works!

Answer (score 1):

```
$lastupdated = `ls -ltr <directory> | tail -n 1`
```

need to do some cutting on the line, but basically this is your last updated file + date.

Comment: No, this gives the date for the folder only! Test it by yourself and you'll see that you're wrong.

Comment: This looks correct to me, unless you need to do a recursive search in all sub-directories of /var/www.  In that case you would need to use the method at http://serverfault.com/a/335384/59925 (suggested by quanta).

Comment: Place a trailing slash at the end of the directory `ls -ltr <directory/>` and this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using the output of GNU stat will help. `stat -x /var/www`

Comment: You're wrong, this gives the date for the folder only. Iv tested it and it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for any file in *and under* the given directory?

For one directory, @Flash's answer works fine. (Although `ls -lt /var/www | head -n 2 | cut -c40-53` is a little bit faster, at the expense of an extra `\n` in the result)

For a whole directory *tree*, you can use a variation on

```
`find /var/www  -type f -printf '%T@\t%TH:%TM on %Tx\t%p\n' | sort -k1 -n | cut -f 2 | head -n 1`
```

Comment: very much as suggested by @quanta, only difference is the formatting being done on each line. quanta's method is probably wiser, you can use $(insert-language-of-choice perl php ...) to convert into your preferred date format without doing so for every file